# Como Hacer dinámico la captura de frames de cámaras y concatenar las salidas en la misma ventana

Tags: python, opencv, cv2

Estoy intentando hacer que el tema de la captura de frames sea dinámico. Es decir, el usuario ingresa la cantidad de cámaras, cada cámara comenzaría a capturar los correspondientes frames. Cada salida de cada cámara se muestra en una ventana, lo que yo quiero lograr además es concatenar todas esas ventanas y mostrarlas una al lado de otra hasta el final de la pantalla, y una vez que llegue al final continuar concatenarlas en la fila de abajo, sería algo así como formar una matriz de ventanitas.

A continuación adjunto el segmento de código de lo que probé, en cual funciona pero solo hasta dos o tres cámaras. Si pongo mas de tres me sale error.

```
#Variables
cap = []
ret = []
frame = []
final = ""
i = 0
cant_camaras = 2

#Inicialización de listas. Las uso para hacer dinámico la captura de frames
for x in range(cant_camaras):
    cap.append(cv2.VideoCapture(x))
    ret.append(x)
    frame.append(x)

#Comienza la captura de frames
while(True):

    ret[i], frame[i] = cap[i].read()

    if i == cant_camaras-1:

        final = cv2.hconcat([cv2.resize(frame[x], (400, 400)) for x in range(cant_camaras)])
        cv2.namedWindow('frame')
        cv2.moveWindow('frame', 0, 0)

        cv2.imshow('frame', final)

        i = 0
    else:
        i = i + 1

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

#Libero las cámaras
for x in range(cant_camaras):
    cap[x].release()

#Destruyo las ventanas
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

El error que me sale al probar con cuatro cámaras es el siguiente:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Camara  0
Camara  1
Camara  2
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wbmte9m7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Camara  3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programacion/Desarrollo/PyCharm/Software Terminal/Automatizacion.Liquidaciones.Mensuales.Colectivos/f_main/c_main/prueba.py", line 80, in <module>
    final = cv2.hconcat([cv2.resize(frame[x], (400, 400)) for x in range(cant_camaras)])
  File "D:/Programacion/Desarrollo/PyCharm/Software Terminal/Automatizacion.Liquidaciones.Mensuales.Colectivos/f_main/c_main/prueba.py", line 80, in <listcomp>
    final = cv2.hconcat([cv2.resize(frame[x], (400, 400)) for x in range(cant_camaras)])
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wbmte9m7\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3929: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wbmte9m7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wbmte9m7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```